# Cómo importar un DataFrame de Python a SQL SERVER

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Estoy tratando de exportar un DataFrame de Pandas a una tabla en SQL Server mediante el siguiente código:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pyodbc
#import urllib

#params = urllib.quote_plus('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ANTO781971-PC\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=KPF_History;UID=sa;PWD=1234')
#engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

mydsn='DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ANTO781971-PC\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=KPF_History;UID=sa;PWD=1234'

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:1234@mydsn')

# write the DataFrame to a table in the sql database
df1.to_sql(Asignacion2, engine)
```

Pero no funciona y recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

`df1` es un DataFrame que tiene la misma estructura que la tabla SQL `Asignacion2`.En la última línea lo que debería pasar, según lo que he podido encontrar, es que se inserten todas las filas del `df1` en la tabla `Asignacion2`.

Comment: ¿El código que compartes falla de alguna manera? Deberías describir cómo y qué es lo que falla. El comportamiento esperado y el que obtienes

Comment: Hola, si, me da un error:  DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: df1 es un data frame que tiene la misma estructura que la Tabla SQL Asignacion2, entonces en la ultima linea lo que deberia pasar segun lo que he podido encontrar es que se inserten todas las filas del df1 en la tabla Asignacion2.

Comment: Si tuvieras un ejemplo de como exportar un data frame en python a sql seria genial, muy agradecido.

Comment: La verdad es que no sé mucho de Python. He añadido tus comentarios a la pregunta y etiquetado con SQL Server también, para ver si alguien que sepa más que yo te puede ayudar. Pero te diría, la tabla "sqlite_master", ¿existe? Porque parece que el problema es que no existe en la base de datos en la que estás conectado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El script básico para exportar a  MSSQL sería el siguiente:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://usuario:contraseña@servidor/baseDeDatos",
                                   echo=False)

data.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Es importante que especifiques adecuadamente el argumento `if_exists` de `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`:

- `'fail'`: Si la tabla ya existe no hace nada. (**Por defecto**)
- `'replace'`: Si la tabla existe la elimina, crea otra e inserta el DataFrame.
- `'append'`: Si no existe, la tabla la crea. Si existe añade los datos nuevos.

Comment: 'servidor='ANTO781971-PC/SQLEXPRESS'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:1234@servidor/KPF_History",echo=False)

df1.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='append')'

Comment: Me da este error:                                                                      
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especific� ning�n controlador predeterminado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')